# How can I get the percentage of total rows with mysql for a group?

Tags: mysql, sql

below I have a query that will get the most common user agents for a site from a table of user agents and a linked table of ip addresses:

```
SELECT count(*) as num, string FROM `useragent_ip`
left join useragents on useragent_id = useragents.id
group by useragent_id
having num > 2
order by num desc, string
```

Sometimes it will show me something like

```
25 Firefox
22 IE
11 Chrome
3  Safari
1  Spider 1
1  Spider 2
1  Spider 3
```

My question is if there is a way that since the numbers on the left represent percentages of a whole, and will grow with time, can I have part of the sql statement to show each group's percentage of the whole? So that instead of using `having num > 2` then I could do something that would say  get the percentage of the total rows instead of just the number of rows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can:

```
select num, string, 100 * num / total as percent
from (
    select count(*) as num, string
    from useragent_ip
    left join useragents on useragent_id = useragents.id
    group by useragent_id) x
cross join (
    select count(*) as total
    from useragent_ip
    left join useragents on useragent_id = useragents.id) y
order by num desc, string;
```

I removed the `having num > 2`, because it didn't seem to make sense.

Answer (score 1):

If you add `with rollup` after your `group by` clause, then you will get a row where `string` is `NULL` and `num` is the total of all the browsers. You can then use that number to generate percentages.

I can't really imagine a single query doing the calculation and being more efficient than using `with rollup`.

Comment: I think it will return the name of last found row in rollup row instead of null. (Not sure)

Comment: couldn't get it to work with the having clause but +1 for a cool command.