# get counts and percentages within groups

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of data that contains question number and response data.

I need to be able to get a count of responses for each option of each question, and also what percentage that represents.

For example data may look like

```
questionNum   ResponseNum
1             1
1             2
1             2
1             2
1             3
2             1
2             1
2             2
```

....and this should then give a result from the query of

```
questionNum     responseNum   count   percent
1               1             1       20
1               2             3       60
1               3             1       20
2               1             2       66
2               2             1       33
```

I can do the query to get counts of each response but don't see a way to get percentages.

Could anyone help here please?

Many thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8753388/how-can-i-get-the-percentage-of-total-rows-with-mysql-for-a-group Using a `CROSS JOIN` against a subquery which only returns the ungrouped `COUNT(*)`, you can divide the current group's `COUNT()` into that total value.

Comment: Also this one's answers are a little clearer to read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768625/calculation-of-percentage-of-group-count

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT a.questionNum, a.responseNum,
        COUNT(*) `count`,
        (COUNT(*) / b.totalCOunt) * 100 Percentage
FROM   table1 a
       INNER JOIN 
        (
          SELECT questionNum, COUNT(*) totalCOunt
          FROM table1
          GROUP BY questionNum
        ) b ON a.questionNUm = b.questionNum
GROUP BY questionNum, responseNum
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/db2ec/7)

you can also add additional function [**FLOOR**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_floor)

```
SELECT a.questionNum, a.responseNum,
        COUNT(*) `count`,
        FLOOR((COUNT(*) / b.totalCOunt) * 100) Percentage
FROM   table1 a
       INNER JOIN 
        (
          SELECT questionNum, COUNT(*) totalCOunt
          FROM table1
          GROUP BY questionNum
        ) b ON a.questionNUm = b.questionNum
GROUP BY questionNum, responseNum
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/db2ec/8)

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding, but thanks for your solution.